# How Do You Configure The Spring Websocket STOMP Server Name?

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket, messagebroker

I am a bit tired of seeing 'connected to server undefined' in the Chrome dev console. How do I give my server a name?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/liarsDice").withSockJS();


    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config){
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

    }
}
```